# Parsing expression with multiplication

Tags: python, pyparsing

So, I have the following parser

```
END = Literal(';').suppress()
POINT = Literal('.')
COMMA = Literal(',').suppress()
COLON = Word(':', exact=1).suppress()
EQUAL = Literal('=').suppress()
VARNAME = Word(alphanums, max=3)
DIGIT = Word(nums, exact=1)
SIGN = oneOf('+ -')
OPER = oneOf('+ - * / ^ ')
NATNUM = DIGIT + ZeroOrMore(DIGIT)
REALNUM = Combine(Optional(SIGN) + NATNUM + Optional(POINT)*1 + NATNUM)
EXRPESS = Forward()
EXRPESS << Combine((REALNUM | VARNAME) + ZeroOrMore(OPER*1 + EXRPESS), adjacent=False)
```

And the expression, something like that 2*y + 7, and it is parsing ok, unfortunately as well as 2y + 7. So how to change EXPRESS to raise an exception if 2 and y come together? 
Thank you

Comment: You've defined VARNAME to accept things like 2y as a potential variable name.

Comment: So, how to correct it?

Comment: Word has a 2-argument constructor as well - if you use that, then the first argument is a string of valid leading characters, and the second is a string of valid body characters. Try `VARNAME = Word(alphas, alphanums, max=3)`.

Comment: @themelok That depends on what your requirements are for this. If you want to allow variables starting with numbers, than this isn't actually a problem. If you don't want to allow variables starting with numbers, change the definition of VARNAME to express that. I'm not certain exactly what that change would be though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in both of that parsers

```
VARNAME = Word(alphas, max=1)
NATNUM = Word(nums) # 1234567890
```

So 2y was the varname, but not Num and Var as i expect.
Thank You.